# imageView inside scrollView not detecting touch

Tags: uiscrollview

I have scrollView added in xib & i am adding an imageview to it programmatically.Now I am not able to detect touch event on this imageview though i have enabled userinteraction for imageview.Actually I want to use the location where the imageview was touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey ! I have found a solution for that. Just make another class as a subclass of UIImageView
and write all your touches method there.They will be invoked

Comment: can you tell me how you had solved it as i am also having the same issue and not able to solve it. Thanks